# SQL Server - Always Round Up or Down Dependent on Condition

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking to force the rounding up or down dependent on a case when statement, regardless of the integer. For example, 1.2345 becomes 1.234 for one condition and 1.235 for the other. Please see below for a chunk of example SQL:

```
select case when action in ('YES') then round(price, 3, 1) 
            when action in ('NO') then round(price, 3) 
            else price end as RoundPrice
```

I also briefly explored `CEILING` & `FLOOR` expressions, but that rounds me off by the whole number. Thanks in advance for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a roundabout way of leveraging the `CEILING` function, see below for SQL:

```
case when action in ('YES') then round(price, 3, 1) 
            when action in ('NO') then CEILING(price*1000)/1000 
            else price end as RoundPrice
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
select case when action in ('YES') then CAST(price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) 
        when action in ('NO') then LEFT(price, 4) 
        else price end as RoundPrice
```

for testing:

```
SELECT CAST(1.1264 AS DECIMAL(10,2))

SELECT LEFT(1.1264,4)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @kim - Thanks very much for commenting. Unfortunately, I was unable to get the LEFT() function to work the desired results has it cuts off the rest of the decimals rather than rounding. Was able to use CEILING, will comment on my question above with results